# SQL Query for one to many bridge table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a logic to return the unique group from **TableGroup** where country of all members from bridge table **TableMember** is equal to US. if any of the member is from other country then it should not show in the result. in this example query should return only Group1

```
CREATE TABLE TableMember
    (
     GroupId INT,
     member varchar(50),
     country VARCHAR(5)
    )
    
    

INSERT INTO TableMember
    VALUES 
    (123, 'member1', 'US'),
    (123, 'member2', 'US'),
    (123, 'member3', 'US'),
    (124, 'member4', 'UK'),
    (124, 'member5', 'US'),
    (124, 'member6', 'US'),
    (125, 'member1', 'IE'),
    (125, 'member2', 'IE'),
    (125, 'member3', 'IE'),
    (126, 'member4', 'UK'),
    (126, 'member5', 'US'),
    (126, 'member6', 'US')

CREATE TABLE TableGroup
(
  GroupId INT,
  GroupName VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO TableGroup
VALUES
(123,'Group1'),
(124,'Group2'),
(125,'Group3'),
(126,'Group4')
```

Comment: Do you want to show a group which has *no* members at all?

Comment: Please don't add images for code or data. Please add `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements (as text) for your sample data, and please show expected results.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with

```
SELECT * FROM TableGroup
WHERE GroupId IN (
  SELECT GroupId
  FROM TableMember
  GROUP BY groupid
  HAVING COUNT(distinct country) = 1
)
```

Live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b341d238cc6559575d7fb45eb625a421

---

If you want to limit to a specific (or specific set of) countries you can do this by first finding any group containing that specific country somewhere and join onto it

```
WITH GroupsContainingUS AS
(
    SELECT GroupID 
    FROM TableMember
    WHERE country='US'
    GROUP BY GroupId
)
SELECT * FROM TableGroup
WHERE GroupId IN (
  SELECT tm.GroupId
  FROM TableMember tm
  INNER JOIN GroupsContainingUS us
      ON tm.GroupId = us.GroupId
  GROUP BY tm.groupid
  HAVING COUNT(distinct country) = 1
)
```

Updated example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53c5978854e270c8b7797245021a3d1a

Comment: You make an assumption - perhaps misled by the limited sample data. Your query returns groups where all members have **the same** country - regardless of wether that country is US. If Group 124 had all members in UK, that group would be included.

Comment: @Jamiec.. Thank you...

Your query is returning all country.. I am looking for a specific country in the result

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85378b197c0c822492482c705f00e35e

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `NOT EXISTS` clause that checks for any members that *don't* match

```sql
SELECT g.*
FROM TableGroup g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TableMember m
    WHERE m.GroupId = g.GroupId
      AND m.Country <> 'US'
);
```

Or if you want to check that there also exist members from `US`

```sql
SELECT g.*
FROM TableGroup g
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TableMember m
    WHERE m.GroupId = g.GroupId
    GROUP BY ()
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN m.Country <> 'US') = 0
);
```